# What does "most recent call last" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I have been programming in Python for a few months already, but understanding errors is still not evident, maybe because I have never taken care of it too much. I would like to know exactly what `most recent call last` means. I understand what `most recent call` means, but the `last` at the end is a bit confusing. Of course I have intuitions, but if someone explains this sentence in detail, it could be clearer also for other non native English speakers' programmers.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of English language (as distinct from programming language error messages) that phrase means:

The most recent call is last.

Ellipsis causes the definite article "the" and the verb "is" to be dropped.

Comment: When I write it out: The most recent call is the last. right?

Comment: Your paraphrase is correct.